# Circular dependency detected, i can't see it

Tags: angular

I'm having a circular dependency warn in my console, but can't resolve it, i know what it is but i'm trying to solve it, but it's useless.

inicio.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { searchClient } from '../../app.module';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.component.css']
})



export class InicioComponent {

  config = {
    indexName: 'items',
    searchClient
  };

  constructor() { 

  }



}
```

app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatIconModule, MatSidenavModule, MatListModule, MatButtonModule } from  '@angular/material';

import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';

import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

import { NgAisModule } from 'angular-instantsearch';

import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './components/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { VerifyEmailComponent } from './components/verify-email/verify-email.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginRegisterComponent } from './components/login-register/login-register.component';
import { InicioComponent } from './components/inicio/inicio.component';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './components/user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { PostItemComponent } from './components/post-item/post-item.component';
import { InboxComponent } from './components/inbox/inbox.component';
import { SendMsgComponent } from './components/send-msg/send-msg.component';

export const searchClient = algoliasearch(
  'hgjhg',
  'ahgjghj'
);


const routes: Routes= [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: InicioComponent},
  { path: 'post-item', component: PostItemComponent},
  { path: 'send-msg', component: SendMsgComponent},
  { path: 'forgot-password', component:  ForgotPasswordComponent },
  { path: 'verify-email', component:  VerifyEmailComponent },
  { path: 'login-register', component:  LoginRegisterComponent },
  { path: 'user-profile', component:  UserProfileComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InicioComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    VerifyEmailComponent,
    LoginRegisterComponent,
    PostItemComponent,
    InboxComponent,
    SendMsgComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    NgAisModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(config),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The problem is with this 2 files, obviously it's with the algoliasearch export to inicio.component.ts and the import from the component to app.module.ts to declare it, but how do i solve the warn? i've tryed many different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in `searchClient`, move it to the file with `InicioComponent`, or to a separate file and import it in `InicioComponent` and in `AppModule`.

Comment: i don't use it in InicioComponent because i don't want to repeat the declaration every time i want to use AlgoliaSearch, i'm using it like 4 times appart from that. 
And the other option, where should i move it? without causing any more problems

Comment: depends what is acceptable for you, if to delete is fine - just delete it so you won't have zombie code. If the removal isn't easy - then create a separate file for searchClient and import it in both places, that's fine. Ideally in an Angular app you should have every declaration in a separate file.

Comment: i wasn't gonna delete anything, lol, both things are 100% important for the project, but i did the other option, thx

Comment: also I'm not sure if you share a secret key in the description near `export const searchClient = algoliasearch`, if it is so - better to replace them with a random values.

Comment: check also here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61489651/revisions, maybe there's a way to hide it from public too.

Comment: or just regenerate the keys in your app

Answer (score 1):

Move the searchClient out of the module and into it's own file.

App.module tries to load InicioComponent, which in turn tries to load the app.module, which tries to load Inicion... repeat forever.

Comment: i ask u the same as to @satanTime